# Array asignment error

Tags: arrays, ruby

I don't understand why the array value changes in two arrays.

```
@arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
other_array = @arr
other_array.each do |value|
  # I delete de element value 4 from array
  other_array.delete(4)
end
```

I printed the values of the array:

```
puts @arr # => [1, 2, 3]
puts other_array # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Why? I deleted an element from `other_array`, not form `@arr`.

Comment: `other_array` is simply referencing the same array in memory as `@arr`. You'll need to copy the array if you want them to be independent. Something ilke `other_array = Array.new(@arr)`

Comment: You need to assign copy of array like `other_array = @arr.dup`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because `other_array` **is** `@arr`.

......................